# find_or_create_by - id = nil when record exists

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to use ActiveRecord's `find_or_create_by` method and I need the ID of returned record. When this method creates a new record this happens. However, if the record already exists, then the ID (along with the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns) is `nil`. All other data is returned just fine. Why is this? I can see it in my database and it has an ID. When I use `find_by` to get the record, the ID is returned. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show the console output? This should not be happening.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue and it was a pretty simple user error.

The `id` of your object will be `nil` if no persisted object was found for the selected attributes, but it can't be fully created (initialized and saved to the db) because it doesn't pass validations.

TLDR; If you use `Model.find_or_create_by(attributes)` and wind up with an object that has `id: nil`, check the errors on it, adjust your attributes, and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

As RachelS says but worse. This seems to happen if validations fail regardless if the record is found first. This is likely to come up if you have uniqueness validations on a column.

```rb
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end

record = Model.create_or_find_by(name: 'test')
record.id # 1

record2 = Model.create_or_find_by(name: 'test')
record2.id # nil
record2.errors # #<ActiveModel::Errors [#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=name, type=taken, options={:value=>"test"}>]>
```

Unfortunately, this [seems intended](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36027) but basically makes `create_or_find_by` unusable as you'll normally want to have uniqueness validation on a unique indexed column which is a prerequisite to `create_or_find_by` in the first place...